# Venn diagram problem solving question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a class of $63$ students, $22$ study biology, $26$ study chemistry and $25$ study physics. $18$ study both physics and chemistry, $4$ study both biology and chemistry and $3$ study both physics and biology. One studies all three subjects.

How many students study:

a) biology only

b) physics or chemistry

c) physics but not chemistry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let |$A$| denote the cardinality of $A$, and let $B,P,C$ denote the set of students studying biology,physics and chemistry respectively. Draw the Venn diagram, and you can see that:

a) for biology only, we have to delete the students in $B\cap C$ and $B\cap P$, but also have to add the students in $B\cup P\cup C$, since we are deleting it twice.

Therefore, number of students studying only biology $$= |B| - |B\cap C| - |B\cap P| + |B\cup P\cup C| = 22-4-3+1 = 16.$$

b) similarly, no. of students studying both physiics and chemistry is$$= |P\cup C|$$ $$=|P|+|C|-|P\cap C| = 25+26-18=33$$.

I hope you can do c) for yourself now. Please ask if you are stuck.

Comment: Ohh i kind of get it now but can you please show me c)? @usersujo

Comment: for c), calculate $|P|-|P\cap C|$. Look at the Venn diagram and it will be clear to you. Also, please don't forget to upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As your title states, you should draw a Venn diagram and insert the relevant information in. From this your can slowly work out the values for each section of the Venn diagram. e.g. if 1 person studies all three and 18 people study both physics and chemistry then 17 people study physics and chemistry but not biology, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I got:

6 = Physics,
5 = Chemistry,
16 = Biology,
17 = Physics + Chemistry,
2 = Physics + Biology,
3 = Chemistry + Biology,
13 = None. 
For C) = 8.

Comment: You need to give steps instead of just the result. Also, try to use mathematical notations which make it easier to read. For example at first sight $5 + 6 < 17$ for Physics + Chemistry?